# Shadow terminator plane in a bowl

Tags: geometry, projective-geometry

When sunlight casts a shadow on an axi-symmetric inside surface we have a $ plane$  determined by rim boundary $B$ projection $E$ and mid centers $C$ on rim that divides illuminated (white) and dark portions (gray is shadow of the bowl itself below $BC$ and yellow is shadow from semicircle radius $CB$) as shown.

One can satisfy this with a parabolic dish of meridian

$$ z = k\,r^2$$

[image: Shadow of Dish]
[image: 3D view Shadow]

How can we formulate this in general to include all meridians producing such shadow partition by a plane ?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand the question. In particular, the upper shaded triangle is confusing; only the sector below is in shade. I also don't see the relevance of the center $C$. If I had to compute the shadow partition, I'd just tilt the dish to put the light on the $\mathbf{r}$ plane (it's easier using a Cartesian coordinate system). Works for both point light sources, as well as directional light sources far enough away to consider all light rays parallel.

Comment: Portion of shade by dish rim $BCE$ separately shown in yellow

Comment: One can satisfy *what* with a parabolic dish?

Comment: @Narasimham: I think I now understand. If you can replace the illustration with a 3D one, I'm sure that would help a lot. I also suspect you could replace *meridian* with *curve* (as in the curve that shapes the dish, as a surface of revolution).

Comment: sorry @Rahul. The dark/ bright region bifurcator is a plane containing EC  parallel to $y$ axis if what is marked as $r$ in the diagram is taken to be the $x$ axis..

Comment: @NominalAnimal I can add a  3D schematic but like to  better compute from a properly derived model.

Comment: I did some numerical exploration, and noticed that the terminator plane does not pass through $C$ at all. I rendered a [simple orthographic image](https://www.nominal-animal.net/answers/dish.png) using POVRay, with light coming directly from far right (light rays parallel), for illustration. $z = (x^2 + y^2)/2$, height $1/2$. I wonder if it would suffice to examine the terminator on the left side of $C$ only? It would definitely be easier!

Comment: Point $C$ is a necessarily the point of tangentcy in the tangent plane at $C$ even without any construction method being considered.The POV ray may not not be accurate enough at end points. Iirc, it was proved also by Prof. Robert Israel like some 4 years ago in response to my question in sci.math.

Comment: @Narasimham: No. I discovered this first using a numerical model (in Awk and Python). When the rays are close enough to horizontal, and the dish is shallow, this is particularly noticeable. Also, POVRay is particularly accurate wrt. shadows. I'll post the math, so you can verify.

Comment: May be others can verify POV  Ray. What do you say about shadow cast inside of a simpler right circular cylinder. Don't you find points $C_1,C_2$ there also? Can you check this?

Comment: @Narasimham: The terminator does cross $C$ for a right circular cylinder (see [here](https://www.nominal-animal.net/answers/cylinder.png); same settings, except for a bit stronger light). For a shallow parabolic dish, consider the surface normal near $C$: the area must be in light, because it is not perpendicular to light rays, nor shadowed by the rim. Or, put in other words, in an orthographic projection, tilting the dish around an axis through $C_1$ and $C_2$ keeps both $C_1$ and $C_2$ visible, unless the dish symmetry axis is away from the viewer (and none of the dish inside visible).

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer, but a report of my findings.  I am hoping that someone better at math can use these to actually answer the question.

---

Let's use a coordinate system where the base of the dish is at origin, the height of the dish is $h$, the radius of the rim is $r$. Let all light rays be parallel, with direction vector $(-1 , 0 , -m)$, $0 \lt m \in \mathbb{R}$. The light rays on the terminator cast by the rim of the dish fulfill
$$z_\text{terminator}(x, y) = m \left(x - \sqrt{r^2 - y^2} \right) + h \tag{1}\label{NA1}$$
Note that $\eqref{NA1}$ applies to all dishes that have a circular rim of radius $r$ at $z = h$.

---

A parabolic dish with base at origin, height $h$, and rim radius $r$, can be defined by
$$z_\text{dish}(x, y) = \frac{h}{r^2} \left( x^2 + y^2 \right) \tag{2}\label{NA2}$$
The light rays on the terminator cast by the dish rim intersect with the inside of the bowl when $0 \le z_\text{terminator}(x, y) = z_\text{dish}(x, y) \lt h$. Solving that for $x$ yields
$$x_\text{terminator}(y) = \frac{m r^2 \pm \left\lvert m r^2 - 2 h \sqrt{r^2 - y^2} \right\rvert}{2 h} \tag{3}\label{NA3}$$
To locate the $y$ coordinate where the terminator intersects the rim, we substitute $\eqref{NA3}$ into $z_\text{dish}(x,y) = h$, and solve for $y$. The result is
$$y_\text{rim} = \pm r \sqrt{1 - \frac{m^2 r^2}{4 h^2}} \tag{4a}\label{NA4a}$$
From $z_\text{terminator}(x, y_\text{rim}) = h$ we can solve the corresponding $x$ coordinate:
$$x_\text{rim} = \frac{m r^2}{2 h} \tag{4b}\label{NA4b}$$
and obviously $z_\text{rim} = h$.

Note that $(x_\text{rim}, y_\text{rim}, z_\text{rim})$ is not the point $C$ in OP's diagram; it is to the right of it. Here is an orthographic projection of $h = 0.5$, $r = 1$, $m = 0.2$ I raytraced in POVRay: [image: example dish]
Note that light comes from right, and the dish is an indentation in the cylinder.

If the slope of the light is small enough, $m \lt \frac{2 h}{r}$, the absolute value term in $\eqref{NA3}$ is negative or zero for $-\lvert y_\text{rim} \rvert \lt y \lt \lvert y_\text{rim} \rvert$. Then,
$$\left\lbrace\begin{aligned}
x_\text{terminator}(y) &= \frac{m r^2}{h} - \sqrt{r^2 - y^2} \\
y_\text{terminator}(y) &= y \\
z_\text{terminator}(y) &= \frac{m^2 r^2}{h} - 2 m \sqrt{r^2 - y^2} + h \\
\end{aligned}\right., \quad \lvert y \rvert \lt \lvert y_\text{rim} \rvert, \; m \lt \frac{2 h}{r} \tag{4c}\label{NA4c}$$
where $z_\text{terminator}(y)$ was obtained by substituting $x_\text{terminator}(y)$ into $\eqref{NA1}$ or $\eqref{NA2}$ (both yield the same result).

We can test for planarity (via [torsion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torsion_of_a_curve)), using the first, second, and third derivatives. The curve is planar if and only if
$$\det \left [ \begin{matrix}
\frac{t}{\sqrt{r^2 - t^2}} & \frac{r^2}{(r^2 - t^2)^{3/2}} & \frac{3 t r^2}{(r^2 - t^2)^{5/2}} \\
1 & 0 & 0 \\
\frac{2 m t}{\sqrt{r^2 - t^2}} & \frac{2 m r^2}{(r^2 - t^2)^{3/2}} & \frac{6 m t r^2}{(r^2 - t^2)^{5/2}} \\
\end{matrix} \right ] = 0$$
This is indeed true for the parabolic dish.

---

Unfortunately, I don't see how to generalize this to other dish profiles, not even to
$$z_\text{dish} = \frac{h}{r^{2 k}}\left( x^2 + y^2 \right)^k$$
except for $k = 1$ (the above parabolic dish case), and maybe $k = 1/2$. The issue is solving $z_\text{terminator}(x,y) = z_\text{dish}(x,y)$ for $x$ (to get $x_\text{terminator}(y)$).

---

Let's consider a right circular cylinder with radius $r$, axis along $z$ axis, and top at $z = h$. In this case,
$$x_\text{cylinder}(y) = \pm\sqrt{r^2 - y^2}$$
and solving $\eqref{NA1}$ for $x$ yields
$$x_\text{terminator}(y, z) = \sqrt{r^2 - y^2} + \frac{z - h}{m}$$
Solving $x_\text{cylinder}(y) = x_\text{terminator}(y, z)$ for $z$ yields
$$z_\text{terminator}(y) = h - 2 m \sqrt{r^2 - y^2}$$
(and $z_\text{terminator}(y) = h$, but that is on the rim).
i.e. the terminator curve is
$$\left\lbrace\begin{aligned}
x_\text{terminator}(t) &= -\sqrt{r^2 - t^2} \\
y_\text{terminator}(t) &= t \\
z_\text{terminator}(t) &= h - 2 m \sqrt{r^2 - t^2} \\
\end{aligned}\right .$$
where $x_\text{terminator}(t)$ was obtained by solving $z_\text{terminator}(y) = z_\text{terminator}(x, y)$ and solving for $x$.
The torsion test (determinant of the matrix formed by the first three derivatives of the terminator curve) is *again*
$$\det \left [ \begin{matrix}
\frac{t}{\sqrt{r^2 - t^2}} & \frac{r^2}{(r^2 - t^2)^{3/2}} & \frac{3 t r^2}{(r^2 - t^2)^{5/2}} \\
1 & 0 & 0 \\
\frac{2 m t}{\sqrt{r^2 - t^2}} & \frac{2 m r^2}{(r^2 - t^2)^{3/2}} & \frac{6 m t r^2}{(r^2 - t^2)^{5/2}} \\
\end{matrix} \right ] = 0$$
Its determinant is (still!) zero, so the terminator cast into a right circular cylinder by a flat rim perpendicular to the axis of the cylinder, is also planar.

[image: Right circular cylinder case]

Comment: What coordinates of $C$ are calculated in each case?

Comment: @Narasimham: As defined in your question, $C_i = (0, \pm r, h)$ in this coordinate system. The actual point where the terminator meets the rim are those points for the right circular cylinder, but $\left(\frac{m r^2}{2 h}, \pm r \sqrt{1 - \frac{m^2 r^2}{4 h^2}}, h \right)$ for the parabolic dish. (In both images, $x$ increases right, $z$ up, and $y$ in and up.)

Comment: @Narasimham: Consider a (reverse path of a) light ray starting from that point: $$\left\lbrace\begin{aligned}x(t) &= \frac{m r^2}{2 h} + t \\ y(t) &= r \sqrt{1 - \frac{m^2 r^2}{4 h^2}} \\ z(t) &= h + m t \end{aligned}\right.$$Substitute into the dish equation, $$h \left ( x^2 + y^2 \right ) - r^2 z = 0$$ and you'll find the only solution is $t = 0$. Adding $\epsilon$ to $x(t)$, $y(t)$, or $z(t)$ lets you explore the region near that point. Although I am often wrong, $\left(\frac{m r^2}{2 h}, \pm r \sqrt{1 - \frac{m^2 r^2}{4 h^2}}, h\right)$ is where the terminator meets the rim of the dish.

Comment: (For a parabolic dish of height $h$ and radius $r$, with center of base at origin, and rim at $z = h$, obviously.)